# Do Kusto Queries Support Short-Circuit (McCarthy) Evaluation

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

I am trying to use the following query fragment to allow for variable regex filter inputs.

```
| where isempty("[[HttpStatusCode]]") or tostring(httpStatus_d) matches regex "[[HttpStatusCode]]"
```

The query is being executed in Azure Log Analytics from within Grafana. I have variables on the Grafana dashboard that allow the user to input a regex expression that feeds into the query. When the filter is empty, I expect no filtering to be applied. I was thinking the Kusto queries may support short-circuiting and when `isempty(..)` evaluated as true, then the remainder of the expression would be ignored and the `matches regex` portion would not execute nor throw an error.

The error message I get when the string is empty is "Relop semantic error: 'matches regex' has the following semantic error: SEM0031: matches regex: argument 2 must be a constant non empty string value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kusto does not have the short-circuit feature. But you can try the workaround below.

First, you need to check if `[[HttpStatusCode]]` is empty or not. If it's empty, you can assign a dummy value to it(Note, please make sure the dummy value cannot be matched by `matches regex` operator in the where cluase). As a result, it will not throw any error when input an empty value.

Sample query:

```
table_name 
| extend tempvalue= iff(isempty("[[HttpStatusCode]]"),"a dummy value","[[HttpStatusCode]]")
| where isempty("[[HttpStatusCode]]") or tostring(httpStatus_d) matches regex tempvalue
```